# Inconsistent list item marker positioning depending on child's display property

Tags: css, html-lists

Considering this markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div id="container">
            <button>toggle display</button>
            <div>text</div>
            <div>text</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Assuming the `#container` element's computed CSS `display` value is `block`, the list item marker (the bullet `•`) is rendered beside the first line of the content (to the left of the `<button>`).

Now, if `#container`'s `display` CSS property is changed to `inline-block`, the list item marker is rendered beside the last line of text. See this [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/wUEsr/2/). (tested in Chrome 35 and Firefox 30).

**Is is possible to render the item marker in the same place in both of these scenarios?** (preferably in the place where it renders with the `display: block` container)

After some fiddling, the item marker position seems to be affected by the `inline-block` element's `vertical-align`. For example, setting `vertical-align: top` in the `#container` element will render the marker close to the top-left of the `inline-block` element, but there is still a discrepancy in the marker positioning as the `vertical-align` property does not apply to `block` elements.

Is there a solution to make the bullet render in the exact same spot independent of the `#container`'s `display` property?

I would prefer a CSS-only solution, but editing the markup is also acceptable.

Comment: You might consider using `:before` to create your own bullets to give you more control.

Comment: @JamesMontagne nice idea, thanks. I guess I could even use `@counter` for numeric/alpha `<ol>`s. However, seems like I'm getting to an easier solution, wrapping the block element inside an inline-block seems to do the trick ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAN5X/)). The bullet is now aligned with the outer `display:inline-block`, but at least it is consistent as I initially requested.

Comment: `display:inline-table` seems fine?

Comment: @Kabie oh I was experimenting with `inline-table`, but then noticed it has the same effect as `inline-block` (which seems less hackish) -- sorry for posting an outdated fiddle revision with `inline-table` in the previous comment. And yes, I guess this is fine. I'll do some more elaborated tests before posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Kabie now I see that I've completely misunderstood your comment, doh. Thanks for posting it as an answer. `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html:

> The baseline of an 'inline-table' is the baseline of the first row of the table.
>
> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

Also see these two demo:

http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block2.html

And it appears that `block` and `inline-table` have the same baseline. So use `inline-table` instead of `inline-block` would solve this.

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks, this is the definitive solution.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to wrap the `#container` with an `inline-block` element:

```
.container-outer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SAN5X/1/)

This way, the bullet is positioned relative to this new outer `inline-block` element, whose display does not change, thus achievement the desired consistency.

The only drawback is that the bullet is aligned with the top of the element (due to the `inline-block` display and `vertical-align: top`) instead of the first line of content as it would be with the the `block` element, but that's barely noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dirty way to do it:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li::before {
    content: "\25CF";
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute; # thanks to DRD
}
```

Comment: Looks nice, thanks. Though, in my production environment, there are ordered lists (`<ol>`s with numeric and alpha counters) which suffer from the same issue, so this solution doesn't apply very well. But thanks for the effort, it may be helpful to someone else in the future.

Comment: That's what matters! ;-D

Comment: @Thauwa.  Add the following rule set: `body {height: 10000px;}` and see what happens with the bullet.  For your approach to work, the `li` should be positioned relatively and the `:before` should be positioned absolutely.  Then, it'll work as intended.

Comment: @DRD, is the positioning for the `li` necessary? It looked fine to me without it. What am I missing?

Comment: I see.  Since you are using `margin-left` it'll work just fine.  If you were to use coordinates (i.e., `left: -20px`), then it would break, because the `:before` would have been positioned using the coordinate system of the `body`.  As it is, you are right, it works good without `position: relative` on the `li`.

Comment: yes, DRD suggested relative positioning the `li` as it would then serve as the containing block for the absolutely positioned pseudo element. However, as absolutely positioned elements' position default to where they'd been in the regular page flow and margins are relative to that position, you don't need the `li` relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that I do not understand why the bullet gets zeroed in on the last block inside an inline-block.  However, if you change the blocks within an inline-block to a `table`, then that seems to fix the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/3BYKp/1/.

```
#container > div {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: They change because of the inline box's baseline, I believe. Anyway, thanks for the answer, though it breaks when arbitrary content follows the button ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BYKp/2/)), though that can be easily fixed by always wrapping that content in a `div`. The only problem is when there's content before the button ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BYKp/3/)), but I haven't mentioned that in the question and I already have an alternative solution for that, so thanks for the effort. `=]`